# Suspicious ssh log entries (“Accepted none for anonymous”)

Tags: ssh, hacking, synology, attacks

I got this log entry chain (and similar repeatedly) on my server:

```
Nov 24 07:38:59 server sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 54.38.81.12-40482;Protocol: 2.0;Client: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
Nov 24 07:38:59 server sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 54.38.81.12-40482;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com;Comp: none [preauth]
Nov 24 07:39:00 server sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 54.38.81.12-40482;Name: anonymous [preauth]
Nov 24 07:39:00 server sshd[28676]: Accepted none for anonymous from 54.38.81.12 port 40482 ssh2
Nov 24 07:39:01 server sshd[28681]: refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 46338, target 167.114.159.146 port 80
Nov 24 07:39:01 server sshd[28681]: refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 47552, target 167.114.159.146 port 80
...
Nov 24 07:39:19 server sshd[28681]: Disconnected from 54.38.81.12
```

I’m pretty sure this was a hacking attack but how to tell if it was successful? Especially unclear is the “Accepted none for anonymous” message. Does it mean that I’ve got a user account named *anonymous* that is allowed to log in with no password and the hacker logged in as *anonymous* and tried to forward some local ports (and there may be some that were forwarded successfully so they didn’t get logged)?

Tried to log in as *anonymous* in a standard way from local network (`ssh anonymous@server`) but got a *permission denied* message.

If I’ve not been hacked, how do I protect against this kind of attack? Already installed *fail2ban* because of other suspicious log entries but this happened after the installation.

*Edit 1:*

Checked the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and found that `PermitEmptyPasswords` was set to `no`. So that should be OK.

*Edit 2:*

I’m not experienced with the `/proc` file system but this is what I discovered:

```
user@server:~$ sudo file /proc/5931/exe
/proc/5931/exe: broken symbolic link to /usr/bin/sshd
user@server:~$ sudo which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

OK, the `file` utility says it’s a broken symbolic link but if I try `sudo hexdump /proc/5931/exe` I get data. Is that normal?

*Edit 3:*

Now I know what’s the reason of *Edit 2.* I mix two systems together. I run a chrooted Debian Stretch on a Synology NAS. And there are processes from both that Debian and the Synology DSM in the /proc file system. Each of the systems has another location of the sshd executable.

*Edit 4:*

This is what `less /proc/*/cmdline` shows:

```
/usr/bin/sshd^@
sshd: user [priv]
sshd: user@pts/4^@
/usr/sbin/sshd^@
sshd: user [priv]
sshd: user@pts/3^@
```

*Edit 5:*

I know that what’s shown here isn’t the suspicious login itself. (Replace `user` with my user name (thoroughly anonymized that output).) The problem is that I’d need to catch the process while the *anonymous* user is logged in. He suddenly disconnects so I can’t watch the process live. How do I forge a trap so I could react to the *anonymous* user login?

Realized that the user *anonymous* is present only on the Synology DSM system. Is it possible that the logs from the DSM system are written also to the chrooted Debian? Tried to disable the FTP and SFTP services because that user belongs to the *ftp* group but the user remains there. There’s neither a `passwd` nor a `usermod` command on the DSM system so I’m not sure how to disable access for that user. *anonymous* has his shell set to `/sbin/nologin` so it should not even be possible to log in via SSH and try port forwards.

*Edit 6:*

Examined the SSH config on the Synology DSM system. Well, there were some settings I changed:

`#PermitEmptyPasswords no` -> uncommented

```
# allow the use of the none cipher
#NoneEnabled no # uncommented
```

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/my-sshd-accepts-root-login-without-password-892320/ indicates that `PermitEmptyPasswords` might possibly be related to the "accepted none". The default for that according to the man page on my system is `no` and that's likely what you'd want.

Comment: Assuming Linux for a second, check /proc/28681, particularly the target of /proc/28681/exe and the contents of /proc/28681/cmdline (or whichever PID is *currently* in fashion on your system), as well as thoroughly review your sshd_config and authentication stores in use. [Edit] your question to indicate your findings. You may have had a breach bad enough that someone got root, and if you have, then nothing you do on that system can be trusted.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect my findings.

Comment: What you show doesn't immediately stand out to me as horrible, which only makes this more curious.

Comment: Edited again to add info on the *anonymous* user and the Synology DSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 6 seems to have solved the issue (at least such kind of attack logs disappeared):

> Examined the SSH config on the Synology DSM system. Well, there were
>   some settings I changed:
>
> `#PermitEmptyPasswords no` -> uncommented
>
> ```
> # allow the use of the none cipher
> #NoneEnabled no # uncommented
> ```